# Rotate Gooey Menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, codepen

I have found this awesome menu on codepen. Now I want to use it, but my problem is that I want to place it right-aligned on my website. Unfortunately this menu drops  also right. But I want it to drop left. So how could I solve this problem. (Change the opening angle didn't work?)
Thanks for your help.

http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp

```
$opening-angle:$pi*2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `transform` property at  `.menu-open:checked~.menu-item` selector

from `transform:translate3d(110px*$i,0,0);` to `transform:translate3d(-110px*$i,0,0);`

And change `left` property to `right` in `.menu` class

Updated `.menu`

```
.menu{
  @extend %goo;
  $width:650px;
  $height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  right:50%; /*Changed*/
  margin-left:-80px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:80px;
  width:$width;
  height:$height;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:right; /*Changed*/
}
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/iamraviteja/pen/JEVbGw?editors=0100)